# Will uninstalling VS Code remove my settings?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I was prompted to reinstall VS Code for Windows due to a new install process that performs a user setup. In the patch notes it says

> Don't worry, all your settings and extensions will be kept during the transition.

And then, when you run the installer, a dialog pops up saying

> Code is already installed on this system for all users. We recommend first uninstalling that version before installing this one. Are you sure you want to continue the installation?

OK, so then I go to uninstall VS Code and a warning pops up

> Are you sure you want to completely remove Visual Studio Code and all of its components?

There is no option to preserve any settings. I might believe that it simply does so without asking the user, but the "completely remove" and "all of its components" bits of the warning have me concerned. Should I go through with this uninstallation? Will all of my preferences be saved?

Comment: You might consider syncing your settings just to be safe: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

Comment: About the fourth time this has been asked - please search first.

Comment: Well, I did search first. I guess just not very well

Comment: I have tried it and it does remove the settings, apart from that it doesn't remove the packages installed.

Answer (score -1):

If you use your personalized account, settings should be synchronized across multiple devices via your account. More here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio

Settings file can be found here:

> %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxxxxx

Comment: this looks to be about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code